# Handling Multi Tenancy on MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, multi-tenant

I would like to ask your opinions regarding the way I handle MultiTenancy. I"m using MVC3 (switching to MVC4) and EF as my backend. I'm using a single app, shared schema MultiTenancy. Below is the code:

```
public abstract class Service<T> where T : Entity
{
    private Repository<T> _repo;
    public Service()
    {
        _repo = new Repository<T>();
    }

    public bool Authenticate(int id)
    {
        //var companyInfo = _authorizationRepository.GetApiKey(apiKey);
        int tenantId = 0; // replaced by companyInfo using repository
        var entity = _repo.GetQuery(tenantId).Where(e => e.Id == id).First();

        if (tenantId != entity.TenantId)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        return true;
    }
}

public class EmployeeService : Service<Employee>
{
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    public EmployeeService()
    {
        employeeRepository = new EmployeeRepository();
    }

    public Employee GetEmployeeById(int employeeId)
    {
        this.Authenticate(employeeId);
        return employeeRepository.GetById(employeeId);
    }
}

public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

Of course DI will be there as well but for simplicity I removed them here (temporarily). I used Generics (feeling dirty about it) on the Service Layer since I'm having trouble on comparing the TenantId with the correct Entity that will be passed on the class. I'm eyeing to recode this using FilterAttributes but I dont have any idea how to. How do you guys handle your multitenancy? Is the design have some crucial flaws that I may encounter on the long run? If you have some samples using FilterAttributes that would be a big help.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is Multitenancy even a concern in a web application?

Comment: @Tejs for me the concern is how I handle routing. Basically both  tenant1.domain.com and domain.com/tenant2 must be valid and point to a specific tenant

Comment: That's cool, but that particular URL scheme has no relation to the persistence layer you decide to use. I guess I'm wondering what your question is.

Comment: @Tejs I was concern with the persistence layer cause I wanted to make sure that TenantA will not get/post any data from TenantB, etc.

Comment: @gnaungayan If your question is answered please mark it. Ty

Comment: I think noone really understood your question. I'm wondering the same... I'm doing authorization logic on repository, but doesn't feel good. Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are building pretty big multi tenancy web app at the moment. Well it's not so simple as it seems but once you build your architecture it's straight forward. Our is deeply in development but you can check out the open source part in nanocms.codeplex.com (we haven't uploaded the db jet butt we will in few days)

Since this is a pretty wide question I'll try to summarize some problems and solutions.

First you need to identify tenant for each request. We have a global action filter that parses url and compares it with data in database. Of course you must cache all data so no calls to database are made. You must not save any of that in a cookie or session because user can visit more than one tenant at the time. I suggest that you put that data in HttpRequest Items so you do that only once in a request but still have that data available always.

For authenticate users must be unique. You must think if you want to give some user different rights on each tenant. If so you must write your authenticate code and even attribute so you can check his role in current tenant. In our app when user authenticates we create session object. In object we have static methods that check for rights in tenant.

I suggest you keep HttpRequest Items strongly typed. We have:

```
public static int TenantID {
    get { return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains("TenantID") ? Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["TenantID"]) : -1; }
    set {
        if (!System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains("TenantID"))
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("TenantID", value);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["TenantID"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Goran. But how do you check if an Entity that will be posted will not go to the wrong tenant. For example TenantA will insert/select a Item how do you ensure that TenantA will not select/insert TenantB's data?

Comment: Please explain are you concerned with security for cross posting or just serving the right content to right tenant? For security you can use anti forgery token it will prevent cross post. For ensuring right content you must have tenantId in every parent table in your database and write queries accordingly.

Comment: Its more like your second statement. If a have a url www.site.com/Employees/1 (this belongs to TenantA data) but TenantB was logged on and hardcoded that url, how do I prevent him from viewing TenantA data?

Comment: You should never send tenantID via URL. That is why we parse incoming request (I mean request URL) to determine current tenant. If I understood your example correctly, you have app that has Employees, lets say tenant a and b. You could have a.site.com/Employees and b.site.com/Employees. By parsing request url you would get access on multiple tenants that you can store in RequestItems like in answer. If you want to check user rights for viewing data you can have table that has complex primary key of userID, tenantID, roleID and you can check if user has rights on that tenant to view/edit data.

Comment: Additionally you should never rely on url or send important data like this. URL is simply navigational and if you must send some important data it should be for one use only and encrypted. To user multi tenant application should be no different than normal app. You can check domain routing and get tenantID from subdomain.